# Installed TFS Console 2015 and have both VS2015 and VS2013 on my VM.Need to run Tests(2013 and 2015) on Same VM

Tags: tfs

In our project we have Unit tests specific to VS2013 and VS2015.We have a requirement of using one build definition (Virtual machine) to run both VS2013 and VS2015 Tests on different timings.

I have installed on that VM Team Foundation Server 2015 Console and created one controller and 2 agents(each for specific version of visual studio).

We are using 2013 build template.

I have ran successfully 2015 UTs on that Virtual Machine(VM) but when I try to run VS2013 specific UTs it is picking up 2015 vstest.exe and throwing exception.

Is there any way to achieve this??

I tried to include MTest Activity build template.Activity is running but it is saying no tests to execute.

I even tried to run throught batch file invoke,this way it is running but through MSTest Activity it is not running scripts.Below is snapshot of TFS log for MSTEST activity

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, TFS calls the corresponding version of VS to run tests. There is no way to specify the VS version for a test in XAML build with default build process template. You would need to customize your build process template by adding InvokeProcess activity to invoke 2013 vstest.exe to run tests.

Since you are using TFS 2015, I'd like to suggest you use new build system, which is tasks based. In new build system, you can add [Visual Studio Test](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/releases/m109/Tasks/VsTest/README.md) task to run tests. In this task, you can specify VSTest version:

[image]

Check this article for more information: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-continuous-testing

Comment: Hi I am using VS2013 build template and it is Xaml build definition.Could you please suggest how to do in this if it is possible

Comment: Yes I customized template.I have included new MStest activity to run the tests still it is picking up latest only.In Mstest Activity ToolPath argument I have specified the MSTest.exe directory path

Comment: Do you have any log? Is MStest activity running during build? Have you checked in the custom build process template? How about running tests with MStest command line manually on your build agent machine?

Comment: Yes Manually it is running.Even Activity is running but it is saying no test found.I will attach the image file in my question.Please see

Comment: The error indicates the file can't be found. Can you see the file on your build agent machine? Do you also build the project with VS 2013?

Comment: Yes the file exists the same Test ran through batch file.

Comment: I'd like to double confirm with you do you manually run the test project on the build agent machine (not your local machine) with MStest command line? From the log, 2013 mstest command line has been called, but it couldn't load some file.